# Camera cant see depth unity shader graph

Tags: unity-game-engine, shader-graph

im making water shader and just realized that i can see water depth effect in editor:[image]

but i cant see it in game window:

[image]

how do i fix this?

Comment: By default camera doesn't have a depth texture, have you enabled it?

Comment: @shingo no, how do i enable it?

Comment: https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/SL-CameraDepthTexture.html

Answer (score 0):

just set "post processing" mark in camera component to enable